# bash & awk: Loop through dir running two separate awk commands on all files and saving in new dir

Tags: macos, bash, awk

I asked a question yesterday and received wonderful help: http://goo.gl/HfovmX

I think I am getting the hang of using awk to solve the problem but I now need to automate some of the work and hope I can do this with bash and awk as well.

To recap from the other thread:

I am using a Mac and have a bunch of text files with no unique identifier tying records to each other.  The only way to tie them together is by noting the position in text files and dealing with them before importing into a stats package.

The solution code is:

```
awk '/^AB1/{ab1=$0;next}/^AB2/{print $1,$2,ab1}' file01.txt > newfile01.txt
```

I was having issues appending the filename to position $7 in the output file, so I ran a second awk command and it worked:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,FILENAME}' newfile01.txt > newnewfile01.txt
```

What I would like to be able to do is point the script at the directory full of these files.  It would ideally run both of the above commands on all *.txt and then save either to a new directory maintaining the same filename (if easier) or saving to the same directory with a new filename (ex: prepend 'new' to the filename).

The end result for me is that I will cat all of the new files into one massive txt file and import into the math programme.  This imported file will now have the filename to help us ID where we got the row in the first place and we will have all information tying the records together on a single line/row, so we can analyze.

Thank you advance for any help/guidance.

Comment: start learning awk and friends. stop `receiving wonderful help`. Btw, if you got *wonderful* help, please accept that answer. This is done by clicking on the check mark beside the question. Damn!

Comment: An idealistic notion, but certainly a goal worth working towards.  In the meantime, I struggle along as best I can.  Thankfully, in the medical field,  when someone asks a question with definitive need, providing wonderful help over and over is an ideal I embody as do most of my colleagues.  I can't recall ever stating nor overhearing the words: "start learning how to do a craniotomy" to a patient in need.  But I digress...  Answer from other thread is accepted.  Apologies for my ignorance regarding proper query procedures.

Comment: I've read trough your problem. When users searching for a *powerful* awk solution, mostly the problems are caused by data structures which aren't well designed and therefore it's hard to post-process them. My first attempt would be to change the output format of the program that produces the files. Is this possible?

Comment: I agree, the data structure is paramount and in this situation we have no option but to use what was given to us.  A long time ago in some abysmal galaxy far far away, someone submitted a tech spec for medical files that did not include proper identifiers nor structures.  Doing a retrospective scan of this stuff necessitates me churning through, but gosh this is frustrating.  I think the solution proposed below will work.

Comment: For the most purposes there is `awk`, for the others as well ;).. I see that you've found a solution. Btw, do you have a name for that type of `medical files`? I could make some research. Might be that there is a parser for such files out there. likely if there is a spec.

Comment: Here is a link to the main specs page: http://www.health.gov.on.ca/en/pro/publications/ohip/default.aspx  I think this was written up sometime in the early 80s.  And, as is sometimes typical of government, someone forgot to think past their nose :)

Comment: ok, much noise!! :) maybe too much for me (without having a good payed job). what is the file extension of such files (maybe better to google)

Comment: they are text ultimately.  To simply on my Mac I appended .txt but they should open with any text editor if you force it

Comment: I've looked through the specification. I'm sure you'll get some software parsers for that files as they are meant for automated processing. I would write an email to that governmental department and ask them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying your proposed solution so that it now iterates through the *txt files in the current directory:

```
for f in *txt ; do awk '/^AB1/{ab1=$0;next}/^AB2/{print $1, $2, ab1}' "$f" > "new$f"; awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,FILENAME}' "new$f" > "newnew$f"; done
```

But I suspect you want the filename of the first file, not the second file:

```
for f in *txt ; do awk '/^AB1/{ab1=$0;next}/^AB2/{print $1, $2, ab1, FILENAME}' "$f" > "new$f"; done
```

Finally, the following multi-line version of the first solution will help you understand what's going on:

```
for f in *txt
do
    awk '/^AB1/{ab1=$0;next}/^AB2/{print $1, $2, ab1}' "$f" > "new$f"
    awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,FILENAME}' "new$f" > "newnew$f"
done
```

You can try these and modify them according to your specific requirements.

Comment: Thank you cabad!  The multiple examples and particularly the final multi-liner really helps me grasp, albeit very basically, the structure of the syntax.  I've given that a whirl and it works!